# How to add edit and delete option in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am creating a html table with this:

```
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
    var myBooks = [
        {
            "Book ID": "1",
            "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
            "Category": "Computers",
            "Price": "125.60"
        },
        {
            "Book ID": "2",
            "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
            "Category": "Programming",
            "Price": "56.00"
        },
        {
            "Book ID": "3",
            "Book Name": "Popular Science",
            "Category": "Science",
            "Price": "210.40"
        }
    ]

    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

Now I want to add two column in below table, with edit and delete option in each row. How can I add that option in below table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, have a look at [ask].

Comment: Small reformat to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(jsonData, function (key, val) {
            var tr = '<tr>';
            tr += '<td>' + (key + 1) + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.id + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
            tr += '<td><a href="#">Delete</a</td>';
            tr += '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(tr);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var myBooks = [
        {
            "Book ID": "1",
            "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
            "Category": "Computers",
            "Price": "125.60"
        },
        {
            "Book ID": "2",
            "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
            "Category": "Programming",
            "Price": "56.00"
        },
        {
            "Book ID": "3",
            "Book Name": "Popular Science",
            "Category": "Science",
            "Price": "210.40"
        }
    ]
var table = document.createElement('table');
var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
table.append(thead);
table.append(tbody);

var headers = Object.keys(myBooks[0]);
var headTr = document.createElement('tr');
tbody.append(headTr);

headers.forEach(function(header) {
  var th = document.createElement('th');
  th.textContent = header;
  headTr.append(th);
});

myBooks.forEach(function(book) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tbody.append(tr);
  headers.forEach(function(bookKey) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = book[bookKey];
    tr.append(td);
  });
});
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].append(table);
```

Comments:

- I'm using the first object's keys to create the headers
- the table is added to `body` as the last step - the less operations on an existing DOM, the more performant your solution is

You could also wrap it in the function:

```
var createTableFromJSON = function(element) {
  // the code from above except the last line

  element.append(table);
}

createTableFromJSON(element);
```

and pass the DOM element you want to add the table under.

Comment: The table u created i want to add one more column dynamically with edit and delete option bcause my code also generate table from json but i m stuck on adding one more column with edit and delete option.

Comment: did the solution provided work? if yes, please accept the answer as correct

Comment: what you are asking for is writing the whole task for you which is not what StackOverflow is for... please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: bro the code u provided was already working in my code and i posted question to ask that how can i add edit and delete option in my dynamic table with edit option but u gave the solution which i did please help me with create table from json with edit and delete option button in each row and i dont want the complete task just guide me...

Comment: i have already created table from json string but i want to add edit button and delete button in each row of table how can i do that ?

Comment: whoa I haven't seen the whole snippet :D sorry for that! my fault

Comment: I don't have time now to provide you with some solution but you can read about `onlick` callback here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: i tried to add button in the above table but the button is getting added in last column but i want to create new column and add button in each row of same table...can anyone help me...